# Font rendering in c++ windows forms

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++

It's small exercise in my programming learning process.
Debug version looks OK:

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvWrt.jpg)

But release version is ugly:

[Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5UIA.jpg)

The problem occur in the same computer. I haven't build installer for others yet. How can I fix it?
Visual C++ Windows Forms, Visual Studio Community 2015, Windows 10.

Comment: Are you using two different computer/OS for debug and release version? Add specific details so people can answer.  By the way you can add image here in stack overflow itself.

Comment: @PranitKothari, One computer. About images: I can't add images because it's impossible for new people here.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, this looks like a resolution issue.  Since debug is often easier and has more checks and balances in place than release, I'd first check out your build settings.  What IDE are you using?

Comment: @SArseneau, Visual Studio Community 2015. Do you have any suggestions, which particular build settings I must check?